# Data is being displayed in the console but not in screen - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to to display the data in the console but unable to display the same in the DOM page using react . I have seen this problem but none of the answers actually work for me .Can you please tell me where I am going . Am I accessing the wrong info in SetData()

```
function Test() {
  const [loading, SetLoading] = useState(false);
  const [questions, SetData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const info = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/info").then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        SetData(res.data.info);
      });
      SetLoading(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);


  return <div>{loading ? questions : <ReactBootstrap.Spinner animation="border" variant="success" />}</div>;
}

export default Test;
```

API data format :

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "question": "Angular 2 integrates easily with NativeScript, allowing you to code your native app in a . . . . . . . . . style that can run on any mobile device platform.",
      "options": ["a) declarative", "b) imperative", "c) interrogative", "d) exclamatory"],
      "answer": 0,
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "Angular 2 components can be described using ________is a way to do some meta-programming.",
      "options": [
        "a) controllers, controller",
        "b) Loaders, loader",
        "c) typescripts, typescript",
        "d) decorators, decorator"
      ],
      "answer": 3,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "question": "The ______ directive substitutes the normal href property and makes it easier to work with route links in Angular 2.",
      "options": ["a) RouterLink", "b) RouterRend", "c) RouterLike", "d) RouterLayer"],
      "answer": 0,
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

[screenshot of the react page for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdwd.png)

Comment: `<div>{loading ? questions : <ReactBootstrap.Spinner animation="border" variant="success" />}</div>` You should switch the ternary condition to `{loading ? spinner : questions}`

Comment: You are calling `setState` in the `.then` block, and `setLoading` outside of it. Maybe it's causing some issues with async calls. Try moving `setLoading` inside, or moving `console.log` and `setData` outside, you are already `await`ing anyway.

Comment: tried it but doesn't work @NickVu

Comment: in `then`, you should call `SetLoading(false)` as well. You never set it back that's why it shows spinner always @vishaalvarshan

Comment: What happens when you try ```console.log(res.data.info)``` in your .then block?

Comment: tried but still the problem is displaying the json data @NickVu

Comment: It says undefined @Ben

Comment: as Ben suggested, you should log to see what you have in `res.data.info` @vishaalvarshan

Comment: i did it says undefined @NickVu

Comment: try to log `res` only, and see what you have. I guess you don't have `res.data.info`, but something else @vishaalvarshan

Comment: There's the probably root of your problem. You're trying to display data that doesn't exist. You need to work out the correct object key to use in SetData(). Log the ```res``` object and look at the output in the console. You should be able to then find the right key to use.

Comment: console.log(res) - displays the data along with status code and some other details @NickVu

Comment: I have tried every combination of object key and still unable to display . Can you help me get the right object or am I doing completely wrong @Ben

Comment: `questions` is an array, you cannot display it directly. You should map it like `questions.map(data => data.question)` @vishaalvarshan

Comment: What do you see when you log ```res```?

Comment: @NickVu you can render arrays – they just appear as raw text

Comment: I guess it will return `[object Object]` @Ben

Comment: No? Wrapping an object/array in a div just displays the object/array as text (similar to the API data displayed in this question). Obviously it's not advisable but I've used if before when I couldn't be bothered to constantly check the console.

Comment: When I try to map it just makes the whole page go blank @NickVu

Comment: When I log it show the  API data along with some meta data like status code and such @Ben

Comment: Could you screencap that and either upload it by editing your question or using Imgur (https://imgur.com/upload)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ECpkXtV screenshot when console logging res @Ben

Comment: Okay, I've got you. I'll write out a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting data into "then" function with await, so, first set the data, and after set loading in true, now your loading keep in screen.

You need set first the loading and after that set the data.

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      //First set loading in true
      SetLoading(true);
      //Then call request
      const info = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/info").then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        //Set data in state
        SetData(res.data.info);
        //remove loading to display the data
        SetLoading(false);
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I am not following you , can you please explain it with some code ?

Comment: I edited the answer, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

The response you are getting from your API call includes an array called `data`. You are treating `res.data` as an object by attempting to access `res.data.info`. This will return undefined and thus you are never updating your `questions` state. I've rewritten your code below. I hope this will work (if it doesn't, it's a step in the right direction). I have also changed it such that when `getData()` is called, the first thing that happens is `loading` is set to true, then the API call is made, then `loading` is set back to false.

```
function Test() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/info").then(res => {
        setQuestions(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);


  return <div>
    {loading ? <ReactBootstrap.Spinner animation="border" variant="success" /> : questions}
   </div>;
}

export default Test;
```